How do I find the possible/supported values for "detail-type" when creating an event bridge rule?
As an example, take the following sample eventbridge rule:
{
  "source": ["aws.route53"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["route53.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["ChangeResourceRecordSets"]
  }
}

In this case, I am hoping to find what other values I might be able to use for detail-type when aws.route53 is the source. Searching hasn't found much on how I can find these, and was hoping there's some documentation in AWS I just can't find or, better yet, a quick way to query this using the aws-cli.  Try as I might, searching isn't yeilding the results I want.
Some additional context for what I'm doing is trying to trigger an AWS Event Bridge rule to trigger a Lambda function when a specific zone in route53 is updated. I tried a sample one for using SNS, trying to modify it to execute a lambda function instead, but can't get it to trigger the eventbridge rule, so am exploring other ways to get this done.

I think you might need to create a CloudTrail trail if you haven't yet for the CloudTrail event to work.

@DMalan I have done that already. Not working, and trying to find other options to get this going is my intent.

Create a catch-all rule to catch all events from the aws.route53 source and log the events to see which ones there are. AWS doesn't publish a full list of event types AFAIK.

Disclosure: EventBridge PM here
Unfortunately, today we don't provide a full list of AWS service events so the above mentioned workarounds apply. However, we have plans to improve this user experience, so this is good feedback!
